# Extract Number of Variable Length from a Text String

Tags: excel, xml, xpath

In my worksheet, cell B14 contains the value **3-6-10**, and in another I have a formula that is designed to separate each number by wrapping XML tags around them.

At the moment, the formula is returning the numbers as a spilled array, but I want to extract a specific one.

I know I could edit the `xpath` argument and use `//segment[1]` to obtain the first, for example. But this isn't great practice because the formula is still returning the three numbers initially.

What is the best solution?

```
=FILTERXML(
"<data><segment>"
&
SUBSTITUTE(B14,"-","</segment><segment>")
&
"</segment></data>",
"//segment"

)
```

Comment: hi, was there an error when using xpath

Comment: with `//segment[1]` FILTERXML will only return the first, so I am not sure what your question is.  Please explain better why `//segment[1]` does not work.

Comment: It is inefficient because the `SUBSTITUTE(B14,"-","</segment><segment>")` part is returning `"3</segment><segment>6</segment><segment>10"`. I want a  modification that allows me to select one of the numbers only.

Using `//segment[1]` is a stopgap solution.

Comment: That would be more difficult than simply using the correct xpath.  But frankly if all you want is the first number then just do: `=--LEFT(B14,FIND("-",B14)-1)`

Comment: That formula will only work for the first number. What about the second and third?

Comment: Again the formula would get way more complicated than just using the xpath.  for example for the 2nd using FILTERXML: `=FILTERXML("<data>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B14,"-","<segment>",1),"-","</segment>",1)&"</data>","//segment")` when `=FILTERXML("<data><segment>"&SUBSTITUTE(B14,"-","</segment><segment>")&"</segment></data>","//segment[2]")` is easier to maintain and read.

Comment: You know you can make the xpath position variable.  `"//segment["&A1&"]"` where a1 holds the number of which one you want to return.